# Get child value with element name

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this `xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:ExportCompanies xmlns="urn:be:fgov:ehealth:samws:v2:company:submit" xmlns:ns2="urn:be:fgov:ehealth:samws:v2:export">
    <ns2:Company actorNr="01716">
        <ns2:Data from="1960-01-01">
            <AuthorisationNr>1716H</AuthorisationNr>
            <VatNr countryCode="BE">0406316776</VatNr>
            <Denomination>Schenker</Denomination>
            <LegalForm>NV</LegalForm>
            <Building>Atlantic House</Building>
            <StreetName>Noorderlaan</StreetName>
            <StreetNum>147</StreetNum>
            <Postcode>2030</Postcode>
            <City>ANTWERPEN</City>
            <CountryCode>BE</CountryCode>
            <Phone>03/5436373</Phone>
            <Language>NL</Language>
        </ns2:Data>
    </ns2:Company>
</ns2:ExportCompanies>
```

With this `xsl` :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="urn:be:fgov:ehealth:samws:v2:company:submit" 
xmlns:ns2="urn:be:fgov:ehealth:samws:v2:export" 

  <xsl:template match="/ns2:ExportCompanies">
    <xsl:for-each select="ns2:Company">
      <xsl:text>INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES ('</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@actorNr" />
      <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="ns2:Data">
        <xsl:sort select="translate(@from,'-','')" order="descending" data-type="number" />
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="@from" />
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="@to" />
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="AuthorisationNr" /> <!--DON'T WORK-->
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="child::*[2]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="child::*[3]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="child::*[4]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="child::*[6]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="child::*[7]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="child::*[8]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="child::*[9]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="child::*[10]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="child::*[11]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="child::*[12]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>');</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The goal is to create a file with `SQL insert` for a database table "COMPANY".

I really don't understand why inside my `<xsl:for-each select="ns2:Data">` i can't simply get the value of first child "AuthorisationNr" using a relative expression!

I can get his value if i use this `child::*[1]` xPath expression but sometimes some child node are missing in the `xml` so i can't use this fixed predicate.

I tried lot of relative/absolute/axis expression before posting this but i think i am missing something..

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your attempt doesn't work is that the `AuthorisationNr` element is in a *namespace* and so are all its siblings.

Instead of declaring a default namespace:

```
xmlns="urn:be:fgov:ehealth:samws:v2:company:submit"
```

in your `xsl:stylesheet` start-tag (which has no effect if your output is meant to be text*), assign it some prefix, e.g.:

```
xmlns:ns3="urn:be:fgov:ehealth:samws:v2:company:submit"
```

then use this prefix to select the elements in this namespace - for example:

```
<xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="ns3:AuthorisationNr" /> 
</xsl:call-template>
```

---

(*) And if your output is meant to be text, then you should say so at the top level of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```